# Can't add ActionBarSherlock maps plugin from Maven

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

My Android project is using Maven to control dependencies and I'm trying to use ActionBarSherlock maps-plugin from Jake Wharton.

I've added Jake's Maven Repository to my pom.xml file and tried to have my local repository updated by using IntelliJ IDEA Update button, but it always returns an error.

Can you help me?

Content from Jake Wharton's github:

```
    <!-- If you are a Maven user you can easily include the library by specifying it as a dependency: -->

    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
       <artifactId>plugin-maps</artifactId>
      <version><!-- LATEST PLUGIN VERSION --></version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Since the Google Maps APIs are not available in central this plugin is deployed to Jake Wharton's personal repository. You can add it with the following: -->

    <repository>
      <id>com.jakewharton</id>
      <url>http://r.jakewharton.com/maven/release</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Is that a published repo? In the end, its just a single class, so you can just copy it and use it directly without bothering too much about using maven for it: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockMapActivity.java

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: The error is "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.zip does not exist"

Comment: I've added the class to my project (also set the package to my project's package) as you suggested, but now I'm getting class not found exception on my class that inherits from SherlockMapActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied the class code to my package and added the following line to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```